# Почему не работает адаптивная вёрстка на телефоне?

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Учусь писать сайты, узнал как делается адаптивная вёрстка, но на телефоне она не работает:

```css
@media (min-width: 570px) {
  body {
    background-color: chocolate;
  }
  #content {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 18%;
  }
  a {
    margin: auto;
    color: chartreuse;
    font-family: fantasy;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 569px) {
  body {
    background-color: chocolate;
  }
  #content {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 35%;
  }
  a {
    margin: auto;
    color: chartreuse;
    font-family: fantasy;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <a href="bi2/index.html">Би-2</a>
  <br>
  <a href="calc/index.html">Калькулятор</a>
  <br>
  <a href="pyatnashki/index.html">Пятнашки(взял с инета)</a>
</div>
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `meta name="viewport"` в `head` добавьте и всё

Comment: @MaximLensky, добавьте ответ с этим тегом и я приму ваш ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Расположение важно, сначала:

```
@media (max-width: 569px) { ... }
```

потом:

```
@media (min-width: 570px) { ... }
```

Рабочий пример на основе Вашего кода:

```css
@media (max-width: 569px) {
  body {
    background-color: chocolate;
  }
  #content {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 35%;
  }
  a {
    margin: auto;
    color: chartreuse;
    font-family: fantasy;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 570px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
  #content {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;  
    margin-top: 18%;
  }
  a {
    margin: auto;
    color: chartreuse;
    font-family: fantasy;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <a href="bi2/index.html">Би-2</a>
  <br>
  <a href="calc/index.html">Калькулятор</a>
  <br>
  <a href="pyatnashki/index.html">Пятнашки(взял с инета)</a>
</div>
```

Так же проверьте, присутствует ли у Вас все [необходимое](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) для того что бы сам "адаптив" был возможен:

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 />
</head>
```

Comment: А скажите, какая разница в порядке в данном случае?

Comment: Вот именно! Никакой, т.к. max-width: 569px и min-width: 570px не перекрывают друг друга.

Answer (score -5):

Попробуйте использовать Bootstrap ( если вы новичок и хотите делать адаптивность не заморачиваясь о медиа-запросах )

Мой совет
`@media (max-width: your width;){ width меньше чем задал в медиа }`

Comment: При чем здесь вообще фреймворки?

Comment: какие фреймворки?

Comment: @VadimChorniy, то есть вы что-то написали и сами не знаете что это? Bootstrap - фреймворк

Comment: Ваш совет аналогичен этому: "Попробуйте есть ложкой, особенно если вы младенец, чтобы не заморачиваться пить из бутылочки". Ответ заслуживает минус.

Comment: осуждаю осужденое